# Disable response of root view in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I've got a `ListView` with several rows. Every row consists of 7 `TextViews` which react to `onClick()` events.

This all works perfectly fine but when the user clicks on the margins of the row, where no `TextView` catches the `onClick()` event, the **root view** - a `LinearLayout` -  **get's highlighted**.

This is normal behaviour of course but as nothing happens by clicking there I don't want the Linear Layout to be highlighted.
Is there any way of **disabling this behaviour** but **keep catching** the **onClick() events** on the `TextView`s?

(The onClick listener is set inside the adapters getView() method)

Here some extract of the xml file. As one can see I've tried some things but they don't work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:longClickable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listelement_weekoverview_tv_mo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/weeklylist_rndrectangle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/appcolor_red_base" />

        ...
</LinearLayout>
```

unclicked version
[image: clicked version]
clicked version
[image: unclicked version]

Comment: This sounds like a hack, but you can set the background of the row item to a drawable resource that always has the same color.

Comment: @Emmanuel I tried setting it to (aet)android:color/transparent but that did not work and I want to keep in transparent.

Comment: You are specifying a color that is not fully opaque. Also a color is not a drawable. You want to use a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Simply overwrite the `isEnabled (int position)` method in your custom Adapter like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled (int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Better approach than mine!